# what is the current range (amp) that could be drawn from the home electricity?

Tags: current

We always hear that home electricity has 220v (depends on country, maybe 110v or etc) voltage. But i cant find anywhere how much ampere we can get from it? So how much is the maximum current that we can draw from a plug in our home?

edition: suppose we talk about a country with 220v, 60Hz. now how much ampere we can draw and what factors determine this current value?

Comment: What wattage do you have for home appliances? What fuses do you have in your distribution panel?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's "too broad". Off the top of my head I can think of an answer which could be reasonably complete (given the basic nature of the question) and still fit into our format. Voting to reopen.

Comment: How much you **can** draw, or how much you **should** draw?  They aren't necessarily the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entirely depends on:

- Country
- Protection devices fitted
- Building code

In the UK a standard socket will provide 230V rated at 13A

Comment: I think that you should find that the voltage rating for a UK socket is more than 230 volts.

Comment: Perhaps rated was poor word choice, provides?

Comment: suppose we talk about a country with 220v, 60Hz. now how much ampere we can draw and what factors determine this current value?

Comment: The main determining factor is the physical wiring of the house. The more current you put through a wire the hotter it gets to the point of burning. Therefore the wiring needs to be of a sufficient gauge and your consumer unit and protection devices ie fuses / RCDs will be rated at a certain current. Your sockets, enclosures and fittings will also have ratings that must not be exceeded. Plus building codes for general safety. Its not a one line answer

Comment: thanks Andy, i get it, it was a clear and good comment.

Comment: @Andyaka the UK harmonized with Europe, so what was once 240 +/-6% is now nominally 230 +10/-6%, and in reality you still get 240V in most areas.  http://coffeetime.wikidot.com/uk-eu-mains-voltage-harmonisation

Comment: @PhilG ... and your point is what or did you mean to address your comment to someone else?

Comment: @TheAndyEngineer the socket is not fused or limited to 13A, the plug for the appliance **does** have a 13A fuse ()or lower). So, the socket could provide up to 32A ie the rated amount for a radial circuit as set by the circuit breaker in the fuse box.

Comment: @SolarMike True, I was coming from a perspective of 'how much current can safely be drawn' Where ring mains in the UK are designed to allow a max of 13A per socket

Comment: @TheAndyEngineer there are other means of connection that are valid and the OP did say "could"... Having seen a 1/4 bolt without head used in place of a 13A fuse for a big welder - the excuse was "well it keeps blowing them"... So, i sorted that as I wanted to use the welder safely...

Answer (score 1):

> ... what factors determine this current value?

- Cable size.
- Connector rating.
- Fusing.